# Check if terminal command is still running in vim/neovim?

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I am currently working on a neovim plugin and have a question that relates to job-control/terminal commands api in Vim/Neovim:

I have a command that needs to be executed in a terminal buffer that has been pre-created with the command: `vim.cmd(':term')`.

After its creation, I now send a command to this terminal with `vim.api.nvim_chan_send(channel_number, 'long_running_proc.exe\r')`, where long_running_proc is a long running process.

The `long_running_proc` does finish after sometime, but I want to query the status of this `long_running_proc` command that is currently running in the terminal emulator(i.e. if it has finished or is still running or failed).

My intention is to keep the same terminal buffer running and reuse it for other `long_running_proc` commands after this, but I want to issue these commands, only after the existing command has finished.

Example Use case:

I want to send a command `Start Sleep -Seconds 10` to Powershell, and immediately the `Start Sleep -Seconds 100` command. But I do not want to send this unless the previous command has finished execution. If I do send the second command, I need it to fail and return with an error something like: "A command is already running! cannot send another command"

Is there a way to do this?

PS: I am currently using the neovim api, but I think there is a significant overlap between both, hence the two tags vim and neovim.

Comment: No, there is practically no overlap. Two completely different implementations.

Comment: I have a feeling that there is no other option rather than checking _pid_ of the process with `tasklist` or `ps` command.

Comment: @MonsieurMerso , is there a way to check if the terminal process is running a command if the PID of the process is known?

Comment: sure, basically you have to play with _ps_\_tasklist_ check docs on those, if it is there, most probably process is running